# electron with react and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I am trying to run a simple electron app with webpack and react.

So I set my webpack with `target: "electron"`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const SassLintPlugin = require('sasslint-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].css',
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
});

module.exports = {
  target: 'electron',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname),
  entry: {
    app: './assets/js/components/index',
    main: './main',
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    path: path.resolve('./dist/'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/js/'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        enforce: 'pre',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/js/'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/scss/'),
        loader: extractSass.extract({
          use: [
            { loader: 'css-loader' },
            { loader: 'sass-loader' },
          ],
          // use style-loader in development
          fallback: 'style-loader',
        }),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['main'],
    }),
    new SassLintPlugin({
      configFile: '.sass-lint.yml',
      context: [path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/scss/')],
      ignoreFiles: [],
      ignorePlugins: [],
      glob: '**/*.s?(a|c)ss',
      quiet: false,
      failOnWarning: false,
      failOnError: true,
      testing: false,
    }),
    extractSass,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Calendar Component',
      template: 'assets/index-template.html',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

My bundles are created correctly into index.html, app.js and main.js and ./dist folder.

But I got an error: Unable to find Electron at my_path_project/dist

My scripts at package.json are:

```
"main": "./dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ./dist/",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack"
  },
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because there is no one. You are install electron to your node modules, you are referring to that in `modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]`.

Simply change your start command to:

```
"main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @Anatoly helped me to appear the electron windows, but I couldn't run react over electron.

So I found this tutorial that worked to run react over electron:
https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-an-electron-application-with-create-react-app-97945861647c

I hope this will help ;)